# Cisco config replace strings with Powershell

Tags: powershell, replace

For security reasons, how can I replace the values after the word "secret"? Cisco config file extract:

```
enable secret 5 $1$362i$gx87nQDZq9RQxXWh2G5p//
!
username juanchis privilege 15 secret 5 $1$cGT9$uJ/rzNxjMvWJnUdPZahTS0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your config is in a file called cisco.cfg:

```
Get-Content ./cisco.cfg | %{$_ -replace '(secret 5) .*','$1 <<ENCRYPTED PASSWORD REMOVED>>'}
```

Here is that idea applied to the script that you've put in the comments:

```
$ParentPath = "C:\cygwin64\home\" 
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $ParentPath -Recurse -Include *.txt
$regex = "(secret 5|secret 9|password|key|pre-shared-key) .*"

foreach ($File in $Files) { 
  $newcontent = Get-Content $File.FullName | %{$_ -replace $regex,'$1 <<ENCRYPTED PASSWORD REMOVED>>'}
  Set-Content -Path $File.FullName -Value $NewContent
}
```

In theory the results of the replace could just be pipelined to add-content, but I'm not sure what the consequences of reading from and writing to the same file are. So safer to collect the output in a variable.

It's worth mentioning that if you run the above script more than once it'll mangle the inserted text as <<ENCRYPTED PASSWORD REMOVED>> itself matches "password" so you'll get <<ENCRYPTED <<ENCRYPTED PASSWORD REMOVED>> REMOVED>>
You may therefore wish to change the inserted text to something that doesn't match the regex e.g. <<CONFIDENTIAL>>

Comment: Tom, your suggestion works perfectly. Thanks a lot for you help.

Comment: For the word "key" I have the following variants:

`tacacs-server key 7 08204F4C0D1E0B03160804566A6Q74
!
crypto isakmp key P@s$w0Rd! address 1.1.1.1  no-xauth`

The script replaces everything after "key", but for the second command it would be deleting valid configurations, how would the regex be so that it only replaces the password portion?

Comment: At the end of the Regex try changing .* to \S*